# How to flush data into db inside active spring transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-test, hibernate-session

I want to test hibernate session's save() method using spring testing framework.
@Test method is :

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testSave() {
    User expected = createUser();
    getGenericDao().currentSession().save(expected);
    User actual = getUser(generatedId);
    assertUsersEqual(expected,actual);
}
```

I want to flush user into database. I want my user to be in database after this method

```
getGenericDao().currentSession().save(expected);
```

Then I want to go to database using spring data framework and fetch this saved user by next line:

```
User actual = getUser(generatedId);
```

I tried to use hibernate flush method like:

```
currentSession().setFlushMode(MANUAL);
//do saving here
currentSession().flush();
```

It does not flush my user into database!
However if I don't make use of @Transactional spring annotation and save my user in programmatic spring transaction I achieve what I want. Unfortunately then user saved into db
is not rollbacked as there is no spring @Transactional. Therefore my test method changes the db and behaviour of subsequent test methods.

So I need to flush my user into db inside test method(not at the end) and at the end of test method rollback all changes to db.

**UPDATE** suggestion to prepare method as follows:

```
@Transactional
public void doSave(User user){
    getGenericDao().currentSession().save(user);
}
```

And call doSave inside testSave is doing nothing. Still I have no user in db after executing this method. I set breakpoint and check my db from command-line.

**UPDATE** Thanks very much for response. The problem is that method flush() does not put my user into database.I tried Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED and it does not put my user into database. I can achieve what I want but only if I turn off spring transaction on @Test method and do saving in programmatic transaction. BUT then @Test method is not rolled back leaving saved user for subsequent @Test methods. Here @Test method to save user is not as dangerous as @Test method to delete user, because it is not rolled back. So there must spring transactional support for @Test method with which I can't anyway put my user(or delete) into db. Actually user is put(or deleted) into db only after @Test method ends and transaction for @Test method is comitted. **So I want to save my User into db in the middle of @Test method and roll back it at the end of @Test method**

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us your GenericDao class also?
EDIT: actually, I think I see the problem.  The current transaction needs to be committed before the data is actually saved to the database.  So you need two @Transactional methods: one to save, and another to load.

Comment: Please look if I did correctly

Comment: Close.  I mean have two transactional functions called by a non-transactional function.  That should work...

Comment: If I make my testSave method non-transactional I will have no rollback after testSave method ends. Thus saved user will remain.

Comment: No Session found for current thread. This is hibernate exception when calling method save of GenericDao. @Transactional on doSave does not work!

Answer (score 15):

Finally I stuck to the following solution:

First, my `@Test` methods are not running within spring `@Transactional` support. See [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html) to know how dangerous it may be. Next, instead of using `@Repository` beans inside `@Test` methods I autowire `@Service` beans which use `@Transactional` annotation.
The miracle is that `@Test` method like this

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void testSave() {
    Answer created = createAnswer();
    Long generatedId = answerService.save(created);
//at this moment answer is already in db
    Answer actual=getAnswerById(generatedId);
... }
```

puts my Answer object into database (just after `answerService.save(created);`) and method `getAnswerById` goes to DB and extracts it to check if save was correct.
To eliminate changes made to database in `@Test` method I recreate database by `JdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript`

Comment: Instead of using JdbcTestUtils you can apply @DirtiesContext annotation.

Answer (score 7):

1. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530878/548473) with warning about `@Transactional` tests ([Spring Pitfalls: Transactional tests considered harmful](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html)). I've used `@org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql` to re-populate DB in my service tests and `@Transactional` for controllers.
2. `ConstraintViolationException` for controller update test with invalid data have been thrown only when transaction is committed. So I've found 3 options:

   - 2.1 Annotate test with `@Commit` or with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)`. Be aware of DB change.
   - 2.2 Use `TestTransaction`

Code:

```
     TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
     TestTransaction.end();
```

- 2.3 Use `TransactionTemplate`

Code:

```
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        String json = ...
        transactionTemplate.execute(ts -> {
            try {
                mockMvc.perform(put(REST_URL + USER_ID)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(json))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
                ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also take care of the importedpackage : 
in my case I imported

> import javax.transaction.Transactional;

instead of

> import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Answer (score 1):

If `flush` is not working then it very much depend on your database isolation level.

`Isolation` is one of the `ACID` properties of database, that defines how/when the changes made by one operation become visible to other concurrent operations.

I believe your isolation level is set to `Read Committed` or `Repeatable Read`.