# With in-mem database for testing, entity manager not releasing locks 'unable to obtain lock'

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2, derby, hsqldb, datanucleus

I have a Spring Boot app with some integration tests inspecting the results from front-end operations on data in the database.

The app uses DataNucleus JPA underneath spring-data-jpa and spring-data-rest, with an in-memory database, e.g. Derby, set up automatically via Spring Boot testing.

I used to use Hibernate, but I swopped it for DataNucleus. The tests all passed with Hibernate, but now my test JdbcTemplate queries are hanging, as though JPA isn't releasing its locks.

I've tried it with H2 (fails silently), Derby (hangs until time-out) and HSQLDB (hangs forever).

I have tried various work-arounds, e.g. without transactions `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.NEVER)` or with/without commits `@Rollback(true/false)`

Spring Boot instantiates the datasource automatically and injects it into the EntityManagerFactory and the JdbcTemplate.

This is the test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
        classes = { TestDataSourceConfig.class })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.DERBY)
@Transactional
public class SymbolRestTests  {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private SymbolRepository symbolRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        symbolRepository.deleteAll();
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateEntity() throws Exception {

        String testTitle = "TEST.CODE.1";
        String testExtra = "Test for SymbolRestTests.java";
        String json = createJsonExample(testTitle, testExtra, true);
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
                post("/symbols").content(json);
        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("Location",
                        containsString("symbols/")));
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.close(); // this didn't help
        String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM symbol WHERE title = ?";
        // exception thrown on this next line
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                sql, new Object[] { testTitle }, Integer.class);
        Assert.assertThat(count, is(1)); 
    }
}
```

and this is the error from HSQLDB (seems to be the most informative):

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
        SQL [SELECT count(*) FROM symbol WHERE title = ?]; 
        A lock could not be obtained within the time requested;  
        nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: 
        A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:259)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:794)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:813)
    at com.gis.integration.SymbolRestTests.shouldCreateEntity(SymbolRestTests.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:316)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(MethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:81)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:93)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.closeOnTransactionError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.movePosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:697)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: ERROR 40XL1: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentLockSet.lockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentLockSet.zeroDurationLockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.AbstractPool.zeroDurationlockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentPool.zeroDurationlockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.RowLocking2nohold.lockRecordForRead(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.heap.HeapController.lockRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.heap.HeapController.lockRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IRowLocking3.lockRowOnPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IRowLocking3._lockScanRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IRowLockingRR.lockScanRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.BTreeForwardScan.fetchRows(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.BTreeScan.fetchNextGroup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BulkTableScanResultSet.reloadArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BulkTableScanResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ProjectRestrictResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ScalarAggregateResultSet.getRowFromResultSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ScalarAggregateResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ProjectRestrictResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BasicNoPutResultSetImpl.getNextRow(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

**Update** using [DataNucleus transaction documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/transactions.html#nontransactional) I have added some DataNucleus-specific properties to the persistence.xml (without result):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
            persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.transactionIsolation" value="read-uncommitted"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**UPDATE #2** 
The log output at DEBUG level showing the DataNucleus-JPA/JdbcTemplate log statements (first the JPA INSERT, then the JdbcTemplate SELECT COUNT(*)):

```
2017-06-09 14:56:18.055 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection(non-enlisted) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@5621a671 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@2006fdaa, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" is being committed.
2017-06-09 14:56:18.055 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection(non-enlisted) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@5621a671 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@2006fdaa, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" closed
2017-06-09 14:56:18.068 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" being inserted into table "SYMBOL"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.071 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection(non-enlisted) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@63a7af06 [conn=null, commitOnRelease=false, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" opened with isolation level "read-uncommitted" and auto-commit=false
2017-06-09 14:56:18.074 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Transaction                  : Running enlist operation on resource: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$EmulatedXAResource@3d4b45b, error code TMNOFLAGS and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=   , enlisted resources=[]]
2017-06-09 14:56:18.076 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection(enlisted) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@63a7af06 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@19d76106, commitOnRelease=false, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" starting for transaction "Xid=   " with flags "0"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.078 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection added to the pool : "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@63a7af06 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@19d76106, commitOnRelease=false, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" for key="org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@2c47a053" in factory="ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl@204c5ddf]"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.125 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Datastore                    : Using PreparedStatement "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@37753b69" for connection "org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@19d76106"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.134 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Datastore.Native             : INSERT INTO SYMBOL (ACTIVE,CREATED,EXTRA,GLOBAL_READ,GLOBAL_WRITE,LAST_MODIFIED,TITLE) VALUES (<'Y'>,<2017-06-09>,<null>,<'N'>,<'N'>,<2017-06-09>,<'TEST.CODE.1'>)
2017-06-09 14:56:18.169 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist            : Execution Time = 36 ms (number of rows = 1) on PreparedStatement "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@37753b69"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.172 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist            : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" was inserted in the datastore and was given strategy value of "1"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.179 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Cache                        : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@93fb44") being changed to be referenced by id="com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity:1" in Level 1 cache
2017-06-09 14:56:18.180 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Cache                        : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" (id="com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity:1") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[YYYYYYYYY]")
2017-06-09 14:56:18.180 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Transaction                  : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" (id="org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference@93fb44") enlisted in transactional cache is now enlisted using id="com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity:1"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.181 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : Insert of object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" is calling insertPostProcessing for field "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity.timeSeriesList"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.181 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Datastore                    : Closing PreparedStatement "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@37753b69"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.181 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : Insert of object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" is calling postInsert for field "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity.timeSeriesList"
2017-06-09 14:56:18.205 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" field "timeSeriesList" is replaced by a SCO wrapper of type "org.datanucleus.store.types.wrappers.backed.List" [cache-values=true, lazy-loading=true, allow-nulls=true]
2017-06-09 14:56:18.207 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : ExecutionContext.internalFlush() process finished
2017-06-09 14:56:18.218 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2017-06-09 14:56:18.220 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT count(*) FROM symbol WHERE title = ?]
2017-06-09 14:56:18.250 TRACE 9492 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [TEST.CODE.1], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2017-06-09 14:57:18.298  INFO 9492 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2017-06-09 14:57:18.390  INFO 9492 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /symbols
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = {X-Application-Context=[application:-1], Location=[http://localhost/symbols/0]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = http://localhost/symbols/0
          Cookies = []
2017-06-09 14:57:18.424 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Transaction                  : Transaction rolling back for ExecutionContext org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@2c47a053
2017-06-09 14:57:18.429 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Lifecycle                    : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" (id="com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity:1") has a lifecycle change : "P_NEW"->""
2017-06-09 14:57:18.447 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Transaction                  : Object "com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1" (id="com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity:1") was evicted from transactional cache
2017-06-09 14:57:18.448 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : Disconnecting com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1 from StateManager[pc=com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity@59c08cf1, lifecycle=P_NEW]
2017-06-09 14:57:18.451 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Cache                        : Object with id="com.bp.gis.tardis.entity.SymbolEntity:1" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 1]
2017-06-09 14:57:18.451 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Transaction                  : Rolling back [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=   , enlisted resources=[org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$EmulatedXAResource@3d4b45b]]
2017-06-09 14:57:18.452 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection(enlisted) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@63a7af06 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@19d76106, commitOnRelease=false, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" rolling back for transaction "Xid=   "
2017-06-09 14:57:18.461 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection(non-enlisted) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@63a7af06 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@19d76106, commitOnRelease=false, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" closed
2017-06-09 14:57:18.461 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Connection                   : ManagedConnection removed from the pool : "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@63a7af06 [conn=org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@19d76106, commitOnRelease=false, closeOnRelease=false, closeOnTxnEnd=true]" for key="org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@2c47a053" in factory="ConnectionFactory:tx[org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl@204c5ddf]"
2017-06-09 14:57:18.462 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Transaction                  : Transaction rolled back in 38 ms
2017-06-09 14:57:18.462 DEBUG 9492 --- [           main] DataNucleus.Persistence                  : ExecutionContext "org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@2c47a053" closed
2017-06-09 14:57:18.463  INFO 9492 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@1f6f0fe2 testClass = SymbolRestTests, testInstance = com.bp.gis.tardis.integration.SymbolRestTests@22604c7e, testMethod = shouldCreateEntity@SymbolRestTests, testException = org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT count(*) FROM symbol WHERE title = ?]; A lock could not be obtained within the time requested; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3a48c398 testClass = SymbolRestTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.bp.gis.tardis.config.TestDataSourceConfig, class com.bp.gis.tardis.config.TestDataSourceConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{logging.level.DataNucleus=DEBUG, logging.level.com.bp.gis.tardis=TRACE, logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE, security.basic.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@1b4ba615 key = [@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackage(), @org.junit.FixMethodOrder(value=NAME_ASCENDING), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Import(value=[class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$Registrar]), @org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=ANY, connection=DERBY), @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=[], excludeName=[]), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith(value=[class org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension]), @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation=REQUIRED, rollbackForClassName=[], readOnly=false, isolation=DEFAULT, transactionManager=, noRollbackFor=[], noRollbackForClassName=[], value=, timeout=-1, rollbackFor=[]), @org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc(webDriverEnabled=true, print=DEFAULT, webClientEnabled=true, secure=true, addFilters=true, printOnlyOnFailure=true), @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration(value=[], exclude=[], classes=[]), @org.junit.platform.commons.meta.API(value=Experimental), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Import(value=[class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector]), @org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMapping(value=spring.test.mockmvc, skip=NO), @org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=MOCK, value=[], properties=[logging.level.DataNucleus=DEBUG, logging.level.com.bp.gis.tardis=TRACE, logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE, security.basic.enabled=false], classes=[class com.bp.gis.tardis.config.TestDataSourceConfig]), @org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMapping(value=spring.test.database, skip=NO), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Import(value=[class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector])]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@702657cc, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6025e1b6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@e30f6a3a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1ff4931d], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

**UPDATE #3**

The logging shows the INSERT by DataNucleus, followed several log statements that all look kosher about entity objects, and then comes

`ExecutionContext.internalFlush() process finished`

which sounds like the DataNucleus EntityManager flushing. Then comes the logging statement from Spring's `JdbcTemplate` which wants to read what JPA insert, and it all goes wrong.

Comment: IIRC The DataNucleus log tells you when a connection is allocated / released (as well as much more), and it uses 1 connection per EntityManager. Closing your EntityManagers?

Comment: Of course - look at the code provided. I have the logging set to debug - I'll post the properties in the pu.xml when i turn my laptop back on

Comment: Try HSQLDB with `hsqldb.tx=mvcc` on the URL. You will need to define a custom data source for this.

Comment: If it goes on like this it'll get to the point soon where Spring Boot is redundant.

Comment: "nontransactional" properties default to those values. As already said, the LOG tells you when a connection is allocated (by DataNucleus) and when released (into whatever pool you are using).

Comment: @NeilStockton not quite sure what you would look for, but I've added the logging to my question, from the point after the schema generation is complete up to the Java stacktrace.

Comment: No idea what the first 2 lines are from ... committing/closing some connection. What comes after shows an Apache Derby (embed) connection being opened read-uncommitted, then used, and then the txn is rolled back (from what code?) and the connection is rolled-back and closed. (look for lines with ManagedConnection in them). Consequently it all looks fine for what DataNucleus is doing IMHO. As said, no idea what is your rollback. You could put entries in the log yourself so you know what statements of yours they align with

Comment: also, suggest that you define where the connections come from. is there some DataSource (Spring?) somewhere and it passes this to DataNucleus, or has DataNucleus been provided with a URL/driverName etc and created a connection pool itself?

Comment: It's a royal pain to read that logging, but do you see the `JdbcTemplate` log statement? It comes right after the DataNucleus flush, at which point the code has also called `entityManager.close()` but DataNucleus/Derby has not let go of the lock. The datasource is supplied by Spring automatically - the same datasource for JPA and for JdbcTemplate. I think I just need to configure JPA to commit its transaction immediately (which I thought `em.flush(); em.close()` would achieve). Spring testing by default though wants to rollback test connections, maybe a problem there.

Comment: "entityManager" is whose entityManager class? Spring wrapper?, DataNucleus?  Is Spring wrapping an underlying DataNucleus JPAEntityManager? The log tells you when DataNucleus JPAEntityManager is closed (and connection released). If it isn't released until after that Spring thing then there is your problem (or Springs problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does in fact totally wrap the `EntityManager` for its testing framework and the wrapper just swallows the call to `entityManager.close()` so that call won't cause transactions to complete.

Spring also throws an error on calls to `entityManager.getTransaction()`.

Typically in my experience of Spring, what *just worked* with the conventional Spring approach, e.g. Spring Data JPA with fully integrated Hibernate, does ***not*** work with DataNucleus.

Thanks go to this SO Q: [How to manually force a commit in a @Transactional method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338150/how-to-manually-force-a-commit-in-a-transactional-method)

I took out the `@Transactional` annotation from the class declaration, and put nothing on the test method, and called a seperate method with `REQUIRES_NEW` to do the REST-to-database functionality I want to test. Then in the original test method after that call, it was all committed and not locked so I could use Spring's JdbcTemplate to examine the result.

```java
@Test
public void shouldCreateEntity() throws Exception {

    String testTitle = "TEST.CODE.1";
    String testExtra = "Test for SymbolRestTests.java";
    String json = createJsonExample(testTitle, testExtra, true);
    log.debug(String.format("JSON==%s", json));
    doInNewTransaction(json);
    String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM symbol WHERE title = ?";
    int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            sql, new Object[] { testTitle }, Integer.class);
    Assert.assertThat(count, is(1));
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void doInNewTransaction(String json) throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
            post("/symbols").content(json);
    mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(header().string("Location",
                    containsString("symbols/")));
}
```

Comment: `em.getTransaction()` will throw an exception if the EntityManager uses JTA transactions; if it isnt then Spring is screwing with the JPA spec