# Want to save data into table in database immediately

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I'm facing an issue with saving data to database using a Spring Data JPA repository.

My scenario: I'm using a loop to collect and save data one by one. It takes a lot of time to collect all the data. Therefore I want to save the data for each record immediately into table into the database. I'm using `saveAndFlush` method but the data is not being saved into the table immediately.

I cannot wait until all the data is collected because it maybe take a full day to collect all.

Comment: Have a look into 'spring data batch insert'

Comment: Make your transaction propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338150/how-to-manually-force-a-commit-in-a-transactional-method

Comment: thanks all! I removed @Transactional from the method, it worked as my expectation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how you test that the data is not written immediately to the database, but I'm guessing you are checking with a separate database connection.

This probably means that your data in deed is written to the database, but not committed and therefore not visible for other sessions.

Make sure that the transaction scope is only *inside* the loop you are using for writing.

For this the method containing the for loop should not have a `@Transactional` annotation or in any other way included in a transaction, while the call to `save` is within a transaction. `saveAndFlush` is not necessary since the transaction commits and this will trigger a flush anyway.

If the call to `save` the only interaction with the database Spring will actually automatically wrap it in a transaction, because repositories are annotated with `@Transactional` out of the box. Otherwise you'll need to use [the transaction support of Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction) to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I removed @Transactional from the method. Thank you, Jens Schauder!

Comment: I'm happy the answer helped. The usual way to say thank you for a helpful answer is to upvote it (up arrow on the left side of the answer). If an answer actually solved the problem, consider marking it as the solution using the check mark. This make it visible to others that the question doesn't need more help anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that saving each record one at a time is a good idea, though it is possible.

*Flushing* is the process of synchronizing the state of the persistence context with the underlying database. If something an expected happens the transaction will be rolled back persisting no data.

The naive solution to your case would be to use separate transactions(*Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW*). Note that this creates a huge performance hog. So, I personly recommend saving a number of records in a single transaction(batching).  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch

So, where ever you use the loop make sure that it runs in a separate transaction from the previous one.

**OR**

If you are using *spring-data-jpa*, there is even simpler way to process entities in a batch. You just need only two things done:

1. In your property file, set the option `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=any_size`
2. Use `saveAll()` method of your repo with the list of entities prepared for inserting.
   Check here for more https://dzone.com/articles/50-best-performance-practices-for-hibernate-5-amp

Check the following images on how *REQUIRES_NEW* and *REQUIRED* do their job:

[image: required]

*AND REQUIRES_NEW*

[image: requires_new]

Comment: I removed @Transactional from the method, it worked as my expectation. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: this works for me and this solution is correct... Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible that your method has a @Transactional annotation, and maybe it waits for all entities to be ready in order to save it all at once in one transaction.

JPA has a 'saveAll' method where you can save a whole collection at once, I suggest you use this one so you don't have to send separate requests for each entity and increasing the DB workload and network bandwidth.

Comment: Explicitly mentioned that saveAll is not an option

Comment: Can you add a piece of code? The whole class or at least a method

Comment: I removed @Transactional from the method, it worked as my expectation. Thanks!