# Spring Batch with Hiberbate , Entity not persisted after flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've a job with one Step. The step has the usual setup.

1. reader: read from a Stock DB-table "instrument"
2. processor: retrieving the latest price from an external service
3. writer: writing the latest price in the price DB-table "instrumentprice"

There is a ItemWriteListener which does some calculations on the latest price in db-table  "instrumentprice". So, it's important that the writer is persisting the latest price immediately in the DB-table "instrumentprice"

In the writer the methods, **persist** and **flush** are called on the **EntityManager** for the Entity "instrumentprice".
But Hibernate doesn't write into the table "instrumentprice" immediately. It does write into the table "instrumentprice" at a later stage, but I haven't figured out the mechanism yet.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.chartinvestbatch.alphaVantageHistory"})
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private ChartInvestJobListener chartInvestJobListener;

    @Bean
    public Job jobAlphaVantage(@Qualifier("stepProcessingPrices") Step stepProcessingPrices) throws IOException {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("JobAlphaVantage")
                .listener(chartInvestJobListener)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepProcessingPrices)
                .build();
    }

}


@Configuration
public class StepConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private TaCalcListener taCalcListener;
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("stepProcessingPrices")
    public Step stepProcessingPrices(HibernateCursorItemReader<Instrument> hibernateCursorItemReader, ItemProcessor<Instrument, InstrumentAndPricesDto> itemProcessor,  ItemWriter<InstrumentAndPricesDto> itemWriter) throws IOException {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("stepProcessingPrices")
                .<Instrument, InstrumentAndPricesDto>chunk(1)
                .listener((ItemWriteListener<InstrumentAndPricesDto>) taCalcListener)
                .reader(hibernateCursorItemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .build();
    }
    
}


@Scope(value = "step")
@Component
@Transactional
public class StockItemWriter implements ItemWriter<InstrumentAndPricesDto> {

    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(StockItemWriter.class);

    @Autowired
    private IntrumentPriceDao intrumentPriceDao;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends InstrumentAndPricesDto> instrumentAndPricesDtoList) throws Exception {

        for (InstrumentAndPricesDto dto : instrumentAndPricesDtoList) {
        
            // check some stuff etc ....

            InstrumentPrice instrumentPrice = new InstrumentPrice();
            instrumentPrice.setDate(dto.getDate());
            ...

            intrumentPriceDao.persist(instrumentPrice);
            intrumentPriceDao.flush();
        }
    }

}



@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public abstract class GenericDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public T persist(final T t) {
        entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    }


    public void flush() {
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}


@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class IntrumentPriceDao extends GenericDao<InstrumentPrice> {

}
```

Comment: How do you determine **Hibernate doesn't write into the table "instrumentprice" immediately**? Flush only synchronize the state of current db session with database, and you only see actual changes in other db session after commit.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in the listener class, then I checked what is written in the DB, and the latest price was not persisted in the DB.

Comment: as @samabcde  you have to differentiate between *persist*, *flush* and *commit*. Check this for a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693836/want-to-save-data-into-table-in-database-immediately/64696713#64696713

Comment: I tied everything ....with/without @Transaction annotation , persist , flush. None had any effect.  What I found out is that the Entity is persisted as soon as the listener (ItemWriterListener) is finished.  So, it's the listener which is prohibiting the entity to be persisted.