# Hibernate's PreUpdateEventListener not being called in unit tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am trying to test my PreUpdateEventListener flow, but I cannot seem to make it work in the JUnit tests. I am not getting any error, but the code is not called.

My PreUpdateEventListener:

```
@Component
public class CandidateListener implements PreUpdateEventListener {

@Autowired
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) this.entityManagerFactory;
    SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
    EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    registry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_LOAD, this);
    registry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_UPDATE, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
    final Object entity = event.getEntity();
    if (entity == null) return false;

    // code here not being called in unit tests, but works fine on server

    return false;
}

}
```

The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class CandidateListenerTest {

@Autowired
CandidateRepository candidateRepository;

@Autowired
EntityAuditEventRepository entityAuditEventRepository;

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Test
public void testHistoryLogging() {
    Candidate cand = new Candidate();
    cand.setEmail("123@gmail.com");
    cand.setFirstName("12");
    cand.setLastName("3");

    cand = candidateRepository.save(cand);

    cand.setLastName("34");
    candidateRepository.save(cand);

    assertEquals(entityAuditEventRepository.findAll().size(), 1);
}

}
```

I have tried injecting the SessionFactory into the test and calling SessionFactory#flush method, but that throws `No CurrentContextSession` error, which I cannot seem to fix.

Comment: HibernateEntityManagerFactory is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this.

What I have kept trying to do was to inject the `EntityManager` and call flush from there, but there would have been no change in the actual output (the code was still not being called).

The solution for me was inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263475/how-to-flush-data-into-db-inside-active-spring-transaction) making my final test look like this:

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void testHistoryLogging() {
    Candidate cand = new Candidate();
    cand.setEmail("123@gmail.com");
    cand.setFirstName("12");
    cand.setLastName("3");

    cand = candidateRepository.save(cand);

    cand.setLastName("34");
    candidateRepository.save(cand);

    assertEquals(entityAuditEventRepository.findAll().size(), 1);

}
```

Basically every call is executed non-transactionally, which saves the candidate into the database after the save method from the repository is called.